# How to link GLFW library to CLION (Windows)?

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, clion, glfw

First I downloaded the GLFW 32 bit binaries for Windows from their website. Below are the contents of this download:

[image: target_link_libraries(myapp glfw)]

I then copied the "include" and "lib-vc2019" files into a folder called "Dependencies" under my Clion project folder "OpenGL":

[image]

Following the instructions from "With CMake and installed GLFW binaries" from https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package

In my CMakeLists.txt file I have the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(OpenGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(OpenGL Main.cpp)

include_directories(Dependencies)

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(OpenGL glfw)
```

When I try to build, I get the following errors:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    glfw3Config.cmake
    glfw3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/moehe/Desktop/CS/CPP/OpenGL/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:194: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Have spent a lot of time on this and very confused. If someone could provide a step by step guidance to make this work, would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: As you've been noted, `find_package` acts as just loading of some other `.cmake` file which defines targets and configures them. It's your duty to place this file in your project. Start off by literally googling `glfw3Config.cmake`, maybe someone has one in their repo

Comment: Instead of wasting more time on this, use [Glitter](https://github.com/Polytonic/Glitter) and be happy.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do. Do either of those *config.cmake files exist?

Comment: If you installed the msys2 binaries they would exist: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw)

Comment: Do I need to install mingw-32 or something?

Comment: I have the file x86_64-w64-mingw32.cmake in there.

Comment: I expect you are using msvc as your compiler in CLion so the link I to msys2 won't work for that.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the "installed" part: those generate a glfw3Config.cmake file that tells CMake where the library and headers live. `find_package` will find and load that file.

Replace the last two lines of your CMake file with the following. This sets up a CMake target with the predefined library and header files:

```
add_library(glfw STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(glfw PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/lib-vc2019/glfw3.lib"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(OpenGL glfw)
```

See the phenomenal [It's time to do CMake right](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) for a good introduction to modern CMake.

Comment: Now I get this error `mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'OpenGL'.  Stop.`

Comment: Isn't that the target you defined yourself?

Comment: Oh, I just copied and pasted your code exactly.

Comment: I think I will go use Visual Studio instead and dump this CLION. Linking a library should not be this complicated.

Comment: The situation is not much better on the visual studio side. Know that cmake can also generate visual studio projects. Do give that Glitter project a try. It is a cmake starter project that contains GLFW and other useful libraries.